# Can I use SSH to authenticate to a podman container?

Tags: docker, containers, podman, podman-compose, podman-in-podman

I have my code deployed on a Podman container, but the container is accessible to anyone using the server with that user. Is there a way I can setup SSH on the container, create a user inside the container and access the container with that user only?
If I setup this SSH authentication will I still be able to use podman exec command and can access the contents of my container?

Comment: another way is to access it remotely via ssh or tcp specifying host like this: `docker -H ssh://user@host exec -it container /bin/sh`, and handle the SSH access or docker daemon tcp service on the server, check https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cli/#a-namehosta-specify-daemon-host--h---host

Comment: When you say "access the container", what operation are you trying to perform?  I'd normally expect you to interact with a container via a published TCP port, and that doesn't have any particular user authentication.

Comment: If you create a container on a machine as user "x", then anyone logged in as "x" will have access to it. Simplest solution is to run it as a different user if you want to prevent access.

Comment: @HernanGarcia
I was able to setup SSH inside the container and create a user inside the container, I don't want to access it remotely, instead I'm looking for this way because, I have a user access of my server and someone else has root access of the server, which gives them a chance to change my password and get into my user account and access the contents of the container. So, I want to setup SSH authentication to the container where I am the root user of the container.

Comment: I'm access my container using podman exec -it <container_name_or_id> sh which takes me into the container where I see all the files. But if someone gets a way into my linux account and uses the same command they would also be into the container which I don't want to happen. Is there a way for it. Please let me know

Comment: @Richard Huxton I'm a user on the server, the root user on the server has a chance of changing my user password and accessing the contents of my container, which I want to avoid. Please help me out if there is a way.

Comment: The purpose of root is to be able to have complete control over the computer, so no. You can limit a root account but only if you too have root-level access and some other security system in place (selinux or similar)